# Should I sell my D50 to buy the new Zoom H6?

Tags: field-recorder, sony-pcm-d50, zoom-h6

What do you guys think - should I sell my D50 to buy the new Zoom H6?
Im a student so I dont have much money, and Ive read that the H6 preamps were OK. Anybody can confirm?

Thing is, I love my D50 but I hate the fact theres no XLR, as well as the fact you cant use it as an audio interface.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no please don't sell your d50, it's such a wonderful recorder!
the zoom might be good (i doubt it but it is possible), but it's not worth it to sell your d50. if you were a freelancer and pay taxes and do investments you've probably already would've paid of the d50.
if i were you i would invest in a clean and simple 2 channel preamp and a good bag. buying gear is an investment of money and time. don't throw away your time and knowledge of the d50, it's a decent piece of gear.

edit: in regards to being a student and audio interface, i don't think the zoom drivers will be a lot better than the onboard drivers of your computer (are you running mac or pc?). a good preamp or portable mixer will be a better investment in the long run. even a student.

cheers

Comment: I 2nd that, no zoom is ever gonna be as reliable or sound better than a d50 or any of sony's portable recorders.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. 
I'm now considering for a Sound Devices preamp but thats quite the investment. :)